# Isolation detection circuit design

Tags: voltage, ltspice, leakage-current

I came across the TIDA-01513 ref design by TI. The site is found over [here](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-01513#design-products).

I have made a simulation of this design but I am not getting the desired results stated in the ref design.

**According to the design:**

[image]

However from the simulation when there is no leakage and when I close S1, the ISO_P does not remain at Vref (2.5V).

**What I should see is this:**

Where RELAY_POS is S1 and RELAY_NEG is S2

[image]

Can someone help me with why I am not getting the results in the doc?

**The simulation is shown below:**
[image]

**Scope images are below:**

1. S1+ and S2+

[image]

2. ISO_P

[image]

3. ISO_N

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't measure on the + side of switches because that is floating. Unless I misunderstood plot 1

Comment: V4 is setup as a pulse from 0 to 5V, hence S1+ should also go from 0 to 5V.

Comment: S1+ is floating when open. You can NOT use single ended measurements. it could have been S1-. so if Vin- is not = Vout, you got a real problem when Sw is open., otherwise possible measurement problems

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the issue was the off resistance was too low.

Comment: the switch DC leakage?